# Issue with node.js loop and db queries

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have to run mysql queries in a loop in Node.js, but what i know it cannot be done in a way I wanned to.

Here is waht I want to achieved:

```
for(var attributename in body){
   sql.increaseValue(attributename, body[attributename]);
}
```

I go to parse and JSON object in which i do not number or names of attributes nor its values.
I know I need to use some kind of callback pattern. I've read many articles about that but in this case i can't move on

Thanks in advance

Radek

Comment: Why cannot you achieve the same results with the single SQL query? I cannot imagine a real situation when you really need to run an SQL query in a loop to achieve some results that cannot be achieved if not by a single query then by some MySQL procedure. And it will be better than making those requests in a loop in nodejs most probably...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that what you want is to know when all of these operations end? When the loop ends? This can be achieved in multiple ways. I assume that your `.increaseValue` method accepts a completion callback. If that's the case, then here's a pseudocode:

```
var finalize = function( ) {
    // for finalization after the loop
};

var requests = [];
for (var attributename in body) {
    (function(attr){
        var req = function() {
            sql.increaseValue( attr, body[ attr ], function( ) {
                var idx = requests.indexOf( req );
                if (idx !== -1) {
                    requests.splice( idx, 1 );
                }
                if (!requests.length) {
                    finalize( );
                }
            } );
        }
        requests.push( req );
    })(attributename);
}

// second loop
for (var i = 0; i < requests.length; i++) {
    requests[i]( );
}
```

Few things worth noting:

1) If `.increaseValue` is truely asynchronous, then you can take advantage of the fact that NodeJS is single-threaded and you can get rid of the second loop and simply call `req( )` after `requests.push( req );`. However if by any chance `.increaseValue` fires synchronously ( for example when an error occures or something ), then this may cause `finalize` to fire immediatly. So do this with caution.

2) You need to wrap `req` definition with an anonymous function because of the scoping.

3) Have a look at [caolan's Async.js library](https://github.com/caolan/async). It might help you greatly with this problem.